# How to make the object as public without removing var in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
(function(){
    var a = {};
    a.b = function(){
        alert('this is b');
    }
}());
```

*How to make the 'a' object as public in above code without removing 'var', means 'a' can access even from another file like below.*

```
(function(){
    a.b();
}());
```

*Note: Dont say to remove 'var', i know that way. But i want to is their any other way that without removing 'var'.*

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Just declare the common variable in a common scope and use it from there.

Comment: If you want to have modular code consider using AMD, CommonJS or Node Browserify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `a` from the IIFE:

```
var a = (function(){
    var a = {};
    a.b = function(){
        alert('this is b');
    }
    return a;
}());
```

or create a property to `window`:

```
(function(){
    var a = {};
    a.b = function(){
        alert('this is b');
    }
    window.a = a;
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can attach it to the global scope.  In web browsers, this is the `window` object.

```
window.a = {};
```

Later on, you can reference it by `window.a` or just `a`.

This is generally discouraged though as collisions can occur when two unassuming scripts run and define the same thing.  It would be much better to wrap whatever you need in closures.

Comment: @Teemu I interpreted that requirement as wanting to explicitly declare a global, not simply avoid removing some syntax.